# Is a nonprofit a business for the purpose of FAA regulations?

Tags: faa-regulations

For the purpose of US aviation regulations that limit flight "in furtherance of a business," is a 501(c)(3) nonprofit corporation considered a business?

Answer (score 2):

By default, yes. The regulations don't care what the tax structure of your business is.

The FAA does support some charitable organizations with relief from certain regulations. For instance, certain volunteer pilot organizations have permission from the FAA to allow their pilots to be reimbursed for some of their costs while working charitably.

It's important to note that these are exceptions that the organization has to specifically ask for and be granted by the FAA, *not* general rules that apply to any 501(c)(3).